# A problem about the tangent bundle of manifold and submanifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, submanifold, tangent-bundle

If $M$ is a regular submanifold of $N$,then for any $x \in M$, use local coordinate,we can naturally take $T_xM$ as a subspace of $T_xN$, now I want to prove $TM$ is a submanifold of $TN$, where $TM,TN$ represent the tangent bundle.

Generally,for two manifold $A,B$, construct a map $f:A \rightarrow B$, such that $f_*:T_xA \rightarrow T_{f(x)}B$ is a monomorphism, thus $f$ is a immerse, then $A$ is a submanifold of $B$.

But I think consider tangent space of a tangent bundle is difficult, I hope someone can give me some hints about my problem. Thanks!

Comment: You can easily build charts for $TM$ and $TN$ out of charts of $M$ and $N$, right?
Now, label $TM$ and $TN$ as $M'$ and $N'$ (forget they are tangent bundles).
Do the same process to build charts of $TM'$ and $TN'$.
It will not be that hard, just verbose.

Now, show that if you had originally considered submanifold charts of $M \subset N$, then the construction gives submanifold charts for $TM' \subset TN'$.

Comment: It is unclear what your problem really is. It seems to be in the 2nd paragraph but that is so poorly written that it's hard to tell.